# Let $\pi$ be a prime element in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. Then $N(\pi)=2$ or $N(\pi)=p$ s.t. $p$ is prime and $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $\pi$ denote a prime element in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ such that $\pi\not\in \Bbb{Z},i\Bbb{Z}$. Prove that $N(\pi)=2$ or $N(\pi)=p$, where $p$ is a prime number $\equiv 1\pmod4$. Give a complete classification of the prime elements of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ using the prime numbers in $\Bbb{Z}$.

This exact question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577152/let-pi-denote-a-prime-element-in-mathbb-zi-pi-notin-mathbb-z-i-math) but I do not understand the answers given, so I will ask it again in hope of further explanation.

Here's everything I know that will probably help me with the problem:

- We know that $\pi=a+bi$ where $a,b\in \Bbb{Z}\setminus \{ 0\}$.
- Fermat's Two Square theorem: A prime number $p\equiv 1 \mod4$
  satisfies $p=a^2+b^2$ where $a\neq b$ and $a,b\in \Bbb{N}\setminus
     \{0\}$.
- $\pi$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$
- If $\pi=xy$ then $\pi \mid x$ or $\pi \mid y$
- If $N(\pi)=2$ then $a=\pm 1, b=\pm 1$.
- If $N(\pi)=p$ where prime $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ then we know $p=a+bi$ for some $a,b\in \Bbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ by Fermat's theorem.

I can't figure out where to start. I was thinking of starting with this:

Let $x,y\in \Bbb{Z}[i]$ such that $x=x_1+x_2 i$ and $y=y_1+y_2i$. Then $\pi\mid x$ or $\pi\mid y$. Suppose $\pi\mid x$.....

Can I have a hint on how to begin this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see that $1+i$ and $1-i$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and the only elements $x\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $N(x)$ are those two, up to multiplication by invertible elements (that is, $1$, $-1$, $i$ and $-i$). In particular $2$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose $p>2$ is a prime integer such that $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. By Fermat's two-square theorem, $p=a^2+b^2$ for some integers $a,b$. Then $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ are not associates in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and they are irreducible.

Indeed, suppose $a+bi=xy$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$. Then
$$
N(x)N(y)=N(a+bi)=a^2+b^2=p
$$
and so either $N(x)=1$ or $N(y)=1$, which is equivalent to the fact that either $x$ or $y$ is invertible.

The same holds of course for $a-bi$.

Note that if $z\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is irreducible, then $\bar{z}$ is irreducible as well, because conjugation is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Now we do the converse.

Suppose $z\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is irreducible. Let $p\mid N(z)=z\bar{z}$, where $p$ is a prime integer. If $p$ is irreducible also in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $p\mid z$ or $p\mid\bar{z}$, but this is the same because $p\in\mathbb{Z}$. Since $z$ is irreducible, then $z=pu$, for some invertible $u$.

If $p$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $p=xy$, where neither $x$ nor $y$ is invertible. and so $p^2=N(p)=N(x)N(y)$ forces $N(x)=N(y)=p$. Therefore both $x$ and $y$ are irreducible, as seen before. Since $x\mid N(z)=z\bar{z}=N(z)$, it's not restrictive to assume that $x\mid z$. Therefore $x=zu$ for some invertible $u$, so $\bar{x}=\bar{z}\bar{u}$ and $x\bar{x}=z\bar{z}$. Similarly, $y\bar{y}=z\bar{z}$, so
$$
p^2=N(p)=N(x)N(y)=x\bar{x}y\bar{y}
$$
and it follows that $z\bar{z}=p$. Thus $N(z)$ is a sum of two squares in $\mathbb{Z}$, so either $N(z)=2$ or $N(z)\equiv1\pmod{4}$.

A prime integer $p$ such that $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Indeed, if $p=xy$, then $p^2=N(x)N(y)$ with $N(x)>1$ and $N(y)>1$, which forces $N(x)=p$. But then $p$ would be the sum of two squares in $\mathbb{Z}$, which is impossible.

In conclusion, the prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are

- $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ where $a^2+b^2$ is a prime integer (so $a^2+b^2=2$ or $a^2+b^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$)
- $p$, where $p$ is a prime integer with $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$

and all associates thereof.

Answer (score 0):

The gaussian primes fall into three following classes

1.all positive rational primes of the form $4k+3$ and their associates.
2.the number $1+i$ and it's associates.
3.all associates to the numbers of the form $x+iy$ such that $x^2+y^2$ is a rational prime of the form $4k+1$.

---

The theory of algebraic numbers-Harry Pollard-p.17

Comment: Is there any simple way to prove this?

Comment: The proof written in the book is the simplest one as i know! However proving that these three classes of Gaussian primes are prime, is very easy! Second and third case is obvious because the norm function is multiplicative, so if norm of a number is prime, then the number itself is prime indeed! For the first case observe that if $p|x^2+y^2$ for some prime $p\pmod 41$ then both numbers $x$ and $y$ are devisible by $p$!

Comment: Is the following statement correct? : Since $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD, then $\pi$ has a unique factorization. Therefore, $N(\pi)$ must be a prime number because if $N(\pi)=N(x)N(y)$ where $N(x),N(y)\neq 1$ then the factorization is not unique.

Comment: Additionally, we know that since $\pi$ is irreducible that either $N(x)=1$ or $N(y)=1$

Comment: No thats not true! The number $3$ has the norm $9$ which is not prime, but we know that $3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[i]$.

Comment: Ok. Let me say "but not all prime numbers satisfy this, either. Consider the three cases $N(\pi)=2,N(\pi)\equiv 1\pmod 4, N(\pi)\equiv 3\pmod 4$....